# Is it possible to Root Lumia 900?

Tags: rooting, flash-player, lumia-900

Is there a root for the lumia 900 yet? Or is anybody working on one? I would like the ability to add flash and the added functionality rooting gives.

Comment: I have never heard of being able to add flash to Internet Explorer on WP7. I also couldn't find any information on it so I doubt that flash is possible.

Comment: @row1 With "flash" he means use custom ROM.

Comment: @VitorCanova actually i mean both. I do want the ability to add adobe flash to the phone, however flashing a custom ROM would (hopefully) fix this issue and allow me to download it.

Comment: Sorry but these are two different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you can't root the Lumia 900.
The first custom ROMs for Lumia 710 and 800 were released some weeks ago, so maybe soon there'll be one for the Lumia 900.

A good place for more information is here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1501